# Export model from blender to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, blender

I want to export a house model from blender to unity and I am facing a problem.
What size should the house be, that is, how to correlate the size of the house in blender and the size in Unity?
And what is the system of disappearance in unity?

Comment: You can scale objects inside unity, and I think there is a unity module that u can install for unity to read blender files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the scale of your object to sync with unity in blender by going to `Scene -> Units` and making sure the `Unit system` dropdown is set to `Metric`. ([Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO6My.png))

After exporting your model, click once on the prefab to see it in the `inspector` menu. Now, go to `Model -> Scene -> Scale factor` and set it to `1`. Also make sure `Convert units` is on. ([Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lOQy.png))

Now your model should be the same size in both blender and unity :)